# Painfully confused on free electron in an "empty" lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons, crystals, electronic-band-theory

I'm trying to study some aspects of solid-state that have always bothered me and I am truly stuck on this conceptual boundary. We take the discrete spatial frequency Fourier Transform to arrive at the central equation

$(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}(q-G)^2 - E)c_{q-G} + \sum_{G'} V_{G-G'} c_{q-G'} = 0$

Where $G$ are the reciprocal lattice vectors.

Now in the free electron case, all Fourier components of the potential go to $0$, leaving a constant that we have the freedom to choose as $0$. Therefore the equation results in

$(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}(q-G)^2 - E)c_{q-G}$=0

Now at this point, one can argue that there might be one reciprocal lattice vector that satisfies the first term in parantheses and all other coefficients trivially go to 0 in the instance of no degeneracy. However, this is where I start to get confused. What does it mean to take the wavevector of a free electron and subtract it by a reciprocal lattice vector? If there is *no* potential, why can the energy dispersion look so wacky?

For example as what I mean by "wacky", Kittel's question 7.2 has us calculate what free electrons for an FCC lattice look like using this equation for different $G$ but a $q$ that points in the $[111]$ direction. I can pick different $G$ values and I get dispersion curves that look like this image in an extended zone scheme. How come there are states that for $k=0$ still have energy if there is *no* potential in the first place? This whole reciprocal lattice subtraction/addition for any plane feels completely artificial.

[image]